# Apache and MySQL doesn't start at boot

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, debian, startup-scripts, update

I am running Debian 6 on a server. On this server I want to have an instance of Apache2 and MySQL started when the system boots.

For this purpose I know there are the init.d script and the symbolic links in the rc.d directories.

I can check the configuration using the `sysv-rc-conf`command:

```
┌ SysV Runlevel Config   -: stop service  =/+: start service  h: help  q: quit ─┐
│                                                                               │
│ service      1       2       3       4       5       0       6       S        │
│ ----------------------------------------------------------------------------  │
│ apache2     [ ]     [X]     [X]     [X]     [X]     [ ]     [ ]     [ ]       │
│ mysql       [ ]     [X]     [X]     [X]     [X]     [ ]     [ ]     [ ]       │
│                                                                               │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

So I try to reboot the machine with the `reboot` command. And then I test my services:

```
root@server:~# /etc/init.d/apache2 status
Apache2 is NOT running.
root@server:~# /etc/init.d/mysql status
MySQL is stopped..
```

I wanted to check the symbolic links but they look ok:

```
root@server:~# ls -l /etc/rc2.d/
(...)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 Mar 12 22:12 S02mysql -> ../init.d/mysql
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  13 Sep 22  2011 S02ssh -> ../init.d/ssh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  17 Mar 12 22:12 S03apache2 -> ../init.d/apache2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  18 Jan 24  2012 S03rc.local -> ../init.d/rc.local
(...)
```

**Do you have any idea why this is not working?**

Comment: have you try to start the service manually ? /etc/init.d/apache2 start or /etc/init.d/mysql start, is it working ?

Comment: post please the output from /var/log/messages or /var/log/syslog there should be some informations on that. otherwise try to start mysqld_safe by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should try and use chkconfig package

```
apt-get install chkconfig

once done, 

chkconfig mysql on 
chkconfig apache2 on
```

if for some reason doesn't work you can add

```
echo "/etc/init.d/mysql start" >> /etc/rc.local
echo "/etc/init.d/apache2 start"  >> /etc/rc.local
```

restart and test

Comment: It works with the chkconfig command, thank you. What is the difference between chkconfig and update-rc.d ?

Comment: chkconfig & update-rc.d both used to updates and queries runlevel information for system services, I find chkconfig easier to use.

Comment: +1 I like the answer, short and to the point :-)

Answer (score 1):

- Check if you can start *Apache2* and *MySQL* manually using the startup scripts inside the **/etc/init.d** directory
- Check the log files, especially **/var/log/syslog**, **/var/log/messages**, **/var/log/apache/** and **/var/log/mysql/**
- Check your runlevel using the **runlevel** command and make sure that the symlinks reside inside the proper **/etc/rc[runlevel].d** directory
- Try to re-enable the symlinks inside the **/etc/rc[runlevel].d** directoried using the **update-rc.d** command

Comment: I didn't not find something revelant in the logs. The solution that user1007727 gave works. Thank you for your help.